# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_id' when doing manual keras backpropagation

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to do manual backpropagation with a keras network but I have started to get an AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_id'.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0.55, 0.52], [0.57,0.50]])
W = np.array([[[1, 2], [2, 1]]], dtype=np.float64)
X_reshape = X.reshape(1, 2, 2, 1)
weights = [np.asarray([[[[1]], [[2]]], [[[2]], [[1]]]]), np.asarray([0])]

model_Conv2D_Transpose = keras.models.Sequential()
model_Conv2D_Transpose.add(keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', input_shape=(2, 2, 1)))
model_Conv2D_Transpose.set_weights(weights)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)

keras_output = model_Conv2D_Transpose.predict(X_reshape).reshape(3, 3)
print(keras_output)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  loss = 1 - keras_output

grads = tape.gradient(loss, model_Conv2D_Transpose.trainable_weights)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model_Conv2D_Transpose.trainable_weights))
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert X to TensorFlow Variable before getting prediction. The tape cannot watch numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The `tape.gradient` function can only compute gradients with respect to variables that are related to `tf.Variable` type or `keras.layers.Layer` type.
Therefore, when using the `tape.gradient` function, the variables that need to be computed for gradients should be defined as `tf.Variable` type or `keras.layers.Layer` type, and added to the model. In this example, we use the `keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose` layer to build the model. Therefore, the trainable variables of the model are the weights and biases of the `Conv2DTranspose` layer. We can use the `model_Conv2D_Transpose.trainable_variables` attribute to obtain these trainable variables and pass them to the `tape.gradient` function.